# Compute $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Tags: limits

> I need to solve the following problem: $$ \lim _{n \mapsto
>  \infty}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\frac{1}{n}}. $$

My attempt:
$$\lim _{n \mapsto
 \infty}\ln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim _{n \mapsto
 \infty}\frac{\ln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)}{n}.$$
Now I want to  prove that
$$\lim _{n \mapsto
 \infty}\frac{\ln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)}{n}=0.$$
But I'm stuck on proving the limit without the Heine theorem (equivalence relation between limit of a sequence and limit of a function). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Title says $(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^\frac{1}{n}$ but then in your answer, you write $\ln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^\frac{1}{n}$. Which one is it ?

Comment: @Ayoub They are equivalent (via exponentiating the second one we get the first).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven They are not. The first converges to $1$, the second to $0$. In general, $u_n^\frac{1}{n}$ and $\ln(u_n)^\frac{1}{n}$ are not equivalent.

Comment: @Ayoub If you reread the question, you will note that the OP uses $\ln(n^{1/n}-1)^{1/n}$ to denote what you probably would write as $\ln((n^{1/n}-1)^{1/n})$ and I hope that you agree with me that then the formulations are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Using Landau notations, $\sqrt[n]{n} -1= \exp(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)) -1= \frac{\ln(n)}{n}+ o\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)$ as $n\to+\infty$

Then $\frac{1}{n}\ln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1) = \frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}+o\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)\right) \to 0$ when $n\to+\infty$

And $(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^\frac{1}{n}=\exp(\frac{1}{n}\ln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)) \to \exp(0)=1$ when $n\to+\infty$

Answer (score 1):

We have for n>2

$\frac{\ln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)}{n} = \frac{\ln\left[\sqrt[n]{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right)\right]}{n}$

$= \frac{\ln(\sqrt[n]{n})}{n}+\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right)}{n}$

$= \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}+\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right)}{n}$

But for x>1, $\ln(x)\leq x-1$ so

$0\leq \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} \leq \frac{n-1}{n^2}$

and the sequence $\left(\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right)\right)_{n\geq 2}$ is bounded...